Why does Node.js randomFillSync runs faster with multiple instances of the same process than with multiple threads?
I have two different approaches to execute crypto.randomFillSync function a given number of times in parallel: one using a Bash script to spawn multiple Node.js processes and another using Node.js worker threads.
Below is a chart illustrating the performance difference between the two approaches for calling the function 10,000,000 times in total:
a chart showing the differences
The tests were run on:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700U
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS x86_64
Node.js version: 22.2.0.
Interestingly, increasing the number of threads from 4 to 8 and from 8 to 16 in the worker threads approach results in even worse performance (in terms of total time taken).
However, using the same setup and running the someLongLoop function from my function.js file or even any other function from the crypto module, there are no such anomalies.
I run the Bash script with a specified number of processes to execute 10,000,000 function calls using the following command:
sh script.sh <NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES> 10000000

I use a similar setup with the threads approach by running the following command:
node main.js <NUMBER_OF_THREADS> 10000000

Here is my setup for both approaches:
script.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the Node.js application file exists
APP_FILE="process.js"
if [ ! -f "$APP_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Error: $APP_FILE not found!"
    exit 1
fi

# Start the timer
start_time=$(date +%s.%3N)

# Extract the arguments
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES=$1
NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS=$2

# Run the processes
for i in $(seq $NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES); do
    node $APP_FILE $NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES $NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS $i &
done

# Wait for all background processes to complete
wait

# Stop the timer
end_time=$(date +%s.%3N)
execution_time=$(echo "$end_time - $start_time" | bc)

printf "Total execution time of the code: %.3f seconds\n" "$execution_time"

process.js
const exec = require('./function');

const start = Date.now();
const NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = +process.argv[2];
const NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS = +process.argv[3];
console.log(`Process No.${process.argv[4]} started`);
const batchSize = exec(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES, NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS);
const end = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
console.log(`Process No.${process.argv[4]} finished running - took: ${end} time, batchSize: ${batchSize}`);

main.js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');

const start = Date.now();
const NUMBER_OF_THREADS = +process.argv[2];
const NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS = +process.argv[3];
let completedThreads = 0;

for (let index = 1; index <= NUMBER_OF_THREADS; index++) {
  const worker = new Worker('./thread.js', {
    workerData: {
      workerNo: index,
      NUMBER_OF_THREADS,
      NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS,
    },
  });

  worker.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(`Thread No.${index} finished running - took: ${msg.time} time, batchSize: ${msg.batchSize} `);
    completedThreads++;

    if (completedThreads === NUMBER_OF_THREADS) {
      const end = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
      console.log(`Total execution time of the code: ${end} seconds`);
    }
  });
}

thread.js
const { workerData, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
const exec = require('./function');

const start = Date.now();
const NUMBER_OF_THREADS = workerData.NUMBER_OF_THREADS;
const NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS = workerData.NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS;
const port = parentPort;
console.log(`Thread No.${workerData.workerNo} started`);
const batchSize = exec(NUMBER_OF_THREADS, NUMBER_OF_FUNCTION_CALLS);
const end = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
port.postMessage({
  batchSize,
  time: end,
});

function.js
const crypto = require('crypto');

function fillTheBuffer() {
  const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024);

  return function () {
    return crypto.randomFillSync(buffer);
  };
}

function someLongLoop() {
  return function () {
    const numberOfIterations = 1_000_000;

    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfIterations; index++) {
      //
    }

    return numberOfIterations;
  };
}

function exec(numberOfWorkers, numberOfFunctionCalls) {
  const batchSize = numberOfFunctionCalls / numberOfWorkers;
  const functionToExecute = fillTheBuffer();

  for (let index = 0; index < batchSize; index++) {
    functionToExecute();
  }

  return batchSize;
}

module.exports = exec;

I checked the Node.js documentation, but did not find any detailed information.
